# Unable to install node 7.5.0

Tags: node.js, curl, docker

I am trying to install nodejs in a docker container

Using curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -

as per the instructions on nodejs.org

But it seems to always install v 0.10.29

Will appreciate any help on this

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just use the prebuilt node Docker image on [DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/)

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl nodejs
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash
```

Comment: Thanks . I am actually trying to make  node available inside a prebuilt Jenkins docker image .

Comment: I am extending a Jenkins image and trying to add nodejs to it . If I add the Jenkins plugin via the Jenkins ui , for some reason my builds fail with error "node not found "

Comment: Thank you . I am exactly doing the same . When I do a node -v I get 0.10.29 . Then after installing npm with apt-get, I get an error saying npm does not support this version of nodejs

Comment: Ah I'm out of idea now. Maybe move that `apt-get install nodejs` after the curl debnodesource.

Comment: I got around by following the steps from the official  nodejs dockerfile :) from https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/master/7.5/Dockerfile

Comment: @Zak glad you found the solution